# Run a function on html form post in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following form in an `.cshtml` file (as part of an ASP.NET web app):

```
<form method="post" action="">
  <fieldset>
    <p><label for="id">id:</label>
       <input type="text" name="id" value="" /></p>

    <p><label for="name">Name:</label>
       <input type="text" name="name" value="" /></p>

    <p><input type="submit" name="buttonSubmit" value="submit" /></p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

And I would like to run a C# command/function on the submit button click. For example, when it gets clicked, I want to run `Console.Write("Yes" + name.)`.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You want that to be server side (C#) or client side (JS)?

Comment: @mjwills Server side.

Comment: It looks for me, that it would be better to use button listener in js for submit button instead of c#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Madno,
if i understand your question correctly and this needs to run server side, I would suggest the following:
Ensure you have added a corresponding Controller for this view(assuming you are using the MVC pattern), should be something like this

```
public class FindAndReplaceController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult FunctionNameInControler(string id, string name)
    {
       return null;
    }
}
```

, and then
change your

```
<form method="post" action="">
```

to something like this

```
<form action="@Url.Action("FunctionNameInControler", "FindAndReplace")">
```

Intern, when the button is clicked, that method will be called.

Comment: I am getting: "InvalidOperationException: Cannot return null from an action method with a return type of 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult'."

Comment: I am assuming you managed to call the function.
wasnt to sure as to what you would of liked to do with the id and name in the function.
to fix the error:
replace "return null;" with 
     return RedirectToAction("index");